# Pullback of the canonical bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, birational-geometry, algebraic-cycles

Let $f : X\to Y$ be a morphism of smooth projective varieties over a field $k$.

Assume $f^*\omega_{Y/k} \simeq \omega_{X/k}$.

I'd like to collect a bestiary of the properties $f$ has, or even criteria/characterizations.

Does the condition $f^*\omega_{Y/k}\simeq \omega_{X/k}$ implies $f$ is finite? (hope: no)

Comment: If $E$ is an elliptic curve, then $f:E\to Spec\, k$ gives a counterexample..

Comment: If $f$ is smooth of relative dimension $d$, then this is saying that $\bigwedge^d \Omega_{X/Y} \cong \mathcal O_X$; in particular the fibres of $f$ have trivial canonical bundle (e.g. a family of elliptic curves, abelian varieties, K3 surfaces, etc.). I think a suitable version with $\bigwedge^d \Omega_{X/Y}$ replaced by the relative dualising sheaf or complex $\omega_{X/Y}$ might hold in bigger generality, but I'm not entirely sure of the precise and most general statement.

Comment: In a slightly different setting, there is the notion of a crepant resolution for normal varieties whose definition is exactly what you're asking for, with $f$ the resolution of singularities for $Y$. These are also not finite.

Comment: @EricCanton: If $Y$ (as assumed) is smooth, it cannot admit a crepant resolution.

Comment: @SándorKovács: indeed, the slightly different setting is when $Y$ is not smooth. I should have made that explicit (and included a $Q$-Gorenstein hypothesis!). Thanks!

Comment: But perhaps more to your point, Sándor, I don't think that smooth varieties admit (non-trivial) proper, birational, crepant morphisms from smooth varieties.