# Pullback of canonical bundle along a group quotient

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a smooth variety over $\mathbb C$ with a free action of an affine algebraic group $H$ over $\mathbb C$. Then there is the quotient map
$$ p: X \to Y := X/H. $$
Suppose $Y$ is smooth projective. I would like to know whether
$ p^* \omega_Y = \omega_X$?

My feeling is yes but I'm having trouble finding the proof. Thanks in advance!

(A comment in [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293235/pullback-of-the-canonical-bundle) seems to provide the converse of what I wanted, but it doesn't seem to answer my question.)

Comment: In this situation we have $\omega_X=p^*\omega_Y\otimes \omega_{X/Y}$ (take the determinant of the short exact sequence of cotangent bundles) and $\omega_{X/Y}=\mathrm{det}(\mathfrak h^\vee)$, where $\mathfrak h$ is the Lie algebra of $H$ (because $p$ is a base change of $*\to BH$). So yes, you get such an isomorphism from a choice of trivialization of (the determinant of) the Lie algebra.